# Docker: how to use SQL file in Directory

Tags: mysql, sql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to open a Wordpress website locally with Docker.

Here is the docker-compose.yml file for this container:

```
version: '3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data:
```

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM orchardup/php5
ADD . /code
```

In the terminal, I enter `docker-compose up -d`. I can then visit the site at `localhost:8080`, but it's not the actual website - it's just a Wordpress template. I'm guessing I have to incorporate the .sql file in the directory somehow? How would I go about doing this? Do I need to specify this in the .yml file?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this `.sql` file? I don't see it included in your question? What does that file contain?

Comment: I'm asking how should I include the .sql file? Are Wordpress themes as well as the entire style of the Wordpress site stored in the .sql file (is this generally how Wordpress sites are kept)? The .sql file is a phpMyAdmin SQL Dump. Someone just downloaded the file from phpMyAdmin to be passed to me. It's a regular old .sql file. I'm just not sure how to call upon this file when booting up Wordpress in a Docker container.

Comment: Do I need to change what I put for `volumes:`?

Comment: As @programmerq pointed, you should elaborate about this question a little bit. What do you mean by "actual website". The one that you have already created and you have it on your host machine? Or maybe this site is somewhere else?

The template (I assume you call it installation page) is shown because wordpress detects that its database is empty.

If I am right with my assumptions you could do sth like [this] (https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) changing first step for creating tarball from __real__ (not contenerized) database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a volume mapping to map a local folder to the /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d container folder, for example : `./init-db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. This file will be loaded on the **first** container startup.

Considering the docker-compose.yml bellow :

1. drop your sql files into `/path-to-sql-files-on-your-host` host folder)
2. run `docker-compose down -v` to destroy containers and volumes
3. run `docker-compose up` to recreate them.

-

```
version: '3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
       - /path-to-sql-files-on-your-host:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data:
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MySQL-Docker documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/), you have a couple of options.

1. After the 'db' docker is running, simply connect to it using the mysql client, and import your .sql dump. Read the section 'Connect to MySQL from the MySQL command line client' If you where not using docker, you would restore this backup like this `mysql fooDB < fooDB_dump.sql` It will be similar with docker commands.
2. Docs, "Initializing a fresh instance", says "...it will execute files with extensions .sh, .sql and .sql.gz that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" That looks more like what you want. Just copy your .sql file into that location within the docker image and then it will automatically parse it.